# Pusher - how to set SERVER ping timeout?

Tags: timeout, pusher

Say user A and user B are subscribed to a presenceChannel.

A disables his wifi.
B's **presenceChannel.getUsers().size()** still shows 2, even after one or two minutes.

B will receive a **userUnsubscribed** event only after **7 mins**.

The below

`options.setActivityTimeout(long ms);
options.setPongTimeout(long ms);`

Sets client timeouts, so they dont help.

Is there a way to shorten the **server** ping timeputs, so that B receives a quick **userUnsubscribed** event?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-java/issues/59), you can't set the server timeout from the client.

> There is not a way for a client to set the server-side timeout, no. We are considering reducing it across the board in order to let other clients know more quickly about disconnections.